# Regex Expression with Conditional formatting in a Google Sheet with tracts

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-forms

So I have to do some conditional formatting for a google spread sheet. Essentially I need to ensure that of a set of data, all of the census tracts that exist in the county need. I want to use conditional formatting to automatically highlight all of the tracts that is in the data set that don't exist in the county. I have a long chain of regex that is not working right now but it contains the data set of tracts that exist in the county. Any suggestions for better solutions would be great.

`=NOT(REGEXMATCH(G1,"^(?:5001|5002|5003|5004|5005|5006|5008|5009.01|5009.02|5010|5011.01|5011.02|5012|5013|5014.01|5014.02|5015.01|5015.02|5016|5017|5018|5019|5020.01|5020.02|5021.01|5021.02|5022.01|5022.02|5023.01|5023.02|5024|5025|5026.01|5026.03|5026.04|5027.01|5027.02|5028|5029.01|5029.02|5029.03|5029.06|5029.07|5029.08|5029.09|5029.10|5030.01|5030.02|5030.03|5031.05|5031.08|5031.10|5031.11|5031.12|5031.13|5031.15|5031.16|5031.17|5031.18|5031.21|5031.22|5031.23|5032.04|5032.07|5032.08|5032.10|5032.11|5032.12|5032.13|5032.14|5032.17|5032.18|5033.04|5033.05|5033.06|5033.12|5033.13|5033.15|5033.21|5033.22|5033.23|5033.24|5033.25|5033.26|5033.27|5033.29|5033.30|5033.31|5033.32|5033.33|5033.34|5033.36|5033.37|5034.01|5034.02|5035.04|5035.06|5035.07|5035.08|5035.09|5035.10|5035.11|5036.01|5036.02|5037.03|5037.07|5037.08|5037.09|5037.10|5037.11|5037.12|5037.13|5038.02|5038.03|5038.04|5039.02|5039.03|5040.01|5040.02|5041.01|5041.02|5042.01|5042.02|5043.07|5043.08|5043.11|5043.14|5043.15|5043.16|5043.17|5043.18|5043.19|5043.20|5043.21|5043.22|5043.23|5044.10|5044.11|5044.12|5044.13|5044.14|5044.15|5044.16|5044.17|5044.18|5044.20|5044.21|5044.22|5044.23|5045.04|5045.05|5045.06|5045.07|5046.01|5046.02|5047|5048.02|5048.03|5048.05|5048.06|5049.01|5050.01|5050.06|5050.07|5050.08|5050.09|5051|5052.02|5052.03|5053.01|5053.02|5053.03|5053.04|5053.05|5054.01|5054.02|5054.03|5055|5056|5057|5058|5059|5060|5061.01|5061.02|5061.03|5062.02|5062.03|5062.04|5063.01|5063.02|5063.04|5063.05|5064.01|5064.02|5065.01|5065.02|5065.03|5066.01|5066.03|5066.04|5066.05|5066.06|5067.01|5067.02|5067.03|5068.01|5068.02|5068.03|5068.04|5069|5070.01|5070.02|5071|5072.03|5072.05|5072.06|5073.01|5073.02|5074.01|5074.02|5075|5076|5077.01|5077.02|5077.03|5078.05|5078.06|5078.07|5078.08|5079.03|5079.04|5079.05|5079.06|5080.01|5080.03|5080.04|5081.01|5081.02|5082.02|5082.03|5082.04|5083.01|5083.03|5083.04|5084.01|5084.03|5084.04|5085.03|5085.04|5085.05|5085.07|5085.08|5086.01|5086.02|5087.03|5087.04|5088|5089|5090|5091.02|5091.05|5091.06|5091.07|5091.08|5091.09|5092.01|5092.02|5093.02|5093.03|5093.04|5094.01|5094.03|5094.04|5095|5096|5097|5098.01|5098.02|5099.01|5099.02|5100.01|5100.02|5101|5102|5103|5104|5105|5106|5107|5108.01|5108.02|5108.03|5109|5110|5111|5112|5113.01|5113.02|5114|5115|5116.08|5116.09|5117.01|5117.02|5117.04|5117.05|5117.07|5118|5119.05|5119.07|5119.09|5119.10|5119.11|5119.12|5119.13|5119.14|5119.15|5119.16|5120.01|5120.05|5120.17|5120.19|5120.20|5120.21|5120.22|5120.23|5120.24|5120.25|5120.26|5120.27|5120.29|5120.30|5120.31|5120.32|5120.33|5120.34|5120.35|5120.36|5120.37|5120.38|5120.39|5120.42|5120.43|5120.45|5120.47|5120.52|5120.53|5121|5122|5123.05|5123.07|5123.08|5123.09|5123.10|5123.11|5123.12|5123.13|5123.14|5124.01|5124.02|5125.03|5125.05|5125.06|5125.08|5125.09|5125.10|5126.02|5126.03|5126.04|5130|5135)$"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not seem like a good use of regex.  You should embed that list somewhere in the spreadsheet and then in your conditional formula use a vlookup inside an isna to deliver a true/false whether it is in the list.

Unfortunately, Google Sheets does not allow the conditional formula to reference off-sheet ranges, so you'll have to keep both lists on the same sheet.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! This makes a lot of sense and my question should have been for better alternatives for regex

Comment: So I tried this,, but for some reason it is not highlighting tracts that do not exist, in fact its not highlighting anything in the specified range. Is there something wrong with my formula?

```=isna(vlookup(G1, $J1:$J372, 2, false))

Comment: Ahh i solved it, the 2 was the problem in the starting point

Comment: Yes, your $J1:$J372 indicates a table that is one column wide, but you asked VLookup to return the second column, so the function threw an error in all cases.